# How to implement the diamond-square algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, terrain, procedural-generation

I was reading this: http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#diamond

And it says:

> This is the starting-point for the iterative subdivision routine,
>   which is in two steps:
>
> **The diamond step:** Taking a square of four points, generate a random value at the square midpoint, where the two diagonals meet. The
>   midpoint value is calculated by averaging the four corner values, plus
>   a random amount. This gives you diamonds when you have multiple
>   squares arranged in a grid.
>
> **The square step:** Taking each diamond of four points, generate a random value at the center of the diamond. Calculate the midpoint
>   value by averaging the corner values, plus a random amount generated
>   in the same range as used for the diamond step. This gives you squares
>   again.

I don't understand this. How does taking the midpoint of every square make a diamond? How does taking the midpoint of every diamond make a square?

Can someone provide language-agnostic code for how to do this?

Edit:

Step 1: you have a grid and make the four corners uniform height:

```
* ┬ ┬ ┬ *
├ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┤
├ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┤
├ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┤
* ┴ ┴ ┴ *
```

Step 2: you take the midpoint of the square and set it to the average of all 4 corners plus a random value:

```
* ┬ ┬ ┬ *
├ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┤
├ ┼ * ┼ ┤
├ ┼ ┼ ┼ ┤
* ┴ ┴ ┴ *
```

Now what? I don't see a diamond anywhere

Comment: The initial iteration is somewhat degenerate.  It should be clearer if you look at steps c->d->e in that link.

Comment: Diamonds are formed only "when you have multiple squares arranged in a grid.  For the moment forgetting about the random perturbation away from the center point of the squares, your diamond shows up like this:  if your first square A is on the left with vertices Atl, Atr, Abl, Abr and midpoint Ac and your second square B is on the right with vertices Btr, Btl, Bbr, Bbl and center Bc then your diamond will have vertices Ac, Atr=Btl, Bc, Bbl=Abr.  The little letters stand for t-top, b-bottom,  l-left, r-right, c-center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put two of the squares together: "this gives you diamonds when you have multiple squares in a grid." Same for above/below the square.

The squaring step makes a new set of squares, offset from the first, with the vertices defined by the diamond's midpoints.

Comment: Oh that kinda makes sense now.

Comment: @RazorStorm Easier to draw the whole thing out on graph paper. There's some fun little games you can play.

Comment: Oh this also explains what the link meant by saying the recursive implementation doesn't give enough information on the diamonds step